# Reading bytes from audio url

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audiotrack

I've mp3 file on a url. I would like to stream it and manipulate the file in real-time, without downloading the whole file first. How can I do it?

I would like to do something like this pseudo code:

```
String fileUrl = "https://..file.mp3";

int chunkIndex = 0;
while (readNext) {
    bytes[] toPlay_chunk_short  = readBytesChunk(fileUrl, CHUNK_SIZE_STEREO, chunkIndex);

    byte[] manipulatedChunk = manipulateChunk(toPlay_chunk_short);

    audioTrack.write(manipulatedChunk, 0, manipulatedChunk.length);

    chunkIndex++;
}
```

And I need to implement 'readBytesChunk' method. I can replace the mp3 to wav on the url if it helps.

Comment: `without downloading the whole file first.` OK. `bytes[] fileUrlBytesArray = readAllBytesFromUrl(fileUrl);` That downloads the file already if it does what the name implies. So dont use it..

Comment: ok, I'll edit the question

Comment: Well what is wrong with your code? It looks that it could work. But we dont know what all these functions do. So tell what you want to know exactly.

Comment: I just wrote pseudo code. I need to implement 'readBytesChunk' method

Comment: I think that readAllBytesFromUrl() has a loop where it reads chunks of bytes. So declare a small buffer of right chunk size and read into the buffer from the inputstream.